# How to make monotouch.dialog work in .net maui

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui

I got a task to migrate an IOS app built with Xamarin.ios to .NET MAUI.

It's almost done, but I'm sticking with this package called MonoTouch.Dialog that is not compatible with. NET.IOS.

What are my alternatives? Is there a way to make this work without rewriting my code? If I need to rewrite, what is a recommended package to help me?

PS: I'm new to the Xamarin environment. I started with this less than a year ago.

Thanks guys!

=D

O look in the nugget for relatives' packages but found nothing. I'm completely lost.

Comment: MT Dialog has not been maintained for **years** and only supports iOS.  Do yourself a favor and rewrite your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MAUI, you can use [Display pop-ups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pop-ups?view=net-maui-8.0):

> Displaying an alert, asking a user to make a choice, or displaying a prompt is a common UI task. .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) has three methods on the Page class for interacting with the user via a pop-up: DisplayAlert, DisplayActionSheet, and DisplayPromptAsync. Pop-ups are rendered with native controls on each platform.

Besides that, you can also use [Popup by .NET MAUI Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup), you can define the layout or style you want.

Comment: Thanks!! I will migrate to this solution.